# automatic backup of remote files

Tags: linux, backup

I have two linux boxes.

**At one there's a cron job that tars a few files.
I want the other box to download it, automatic.**

Now, I intentionally didn't specify any method to achieve this because I simply might limit myself with an average solution.

---

Searching the web, I could use **rsync** but there are no concise examples.

Another option would be to create a **dedicated SSH user with very limited rights** (dir jail, no dir listing etc'), which will be used by the slave box to download the tarball.

What options do I have? Any link to a good example?

Requirements: Currently I don't mind about bandwidth etc'. The file is not too big anyway.

Comment: you want to copy the tar file created by cron job right?

Answer (score 1):

This is for password less login.

First create a `id_rsa.pub` key using this method

```
[max@localhost .ssh]$ ssh-keygen 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/max/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/max/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/max/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
93:24:83:37:eb:5e:13:97:d1:ea:bd:0a:d8:29:9f:ba max@localhost.localdomain
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|     .     .     |
|    . = . . .    |
|     . * . +     |
|      . S +      |
|     . o * .     |
|      + * . .    |
|     . + +   .   |
|      Eoo ...    |
+-----------------+
```

Share `id_rsa.pub` key to remote system

This key will present under `.ssh/` directory under your home directory

Using this command you can copy the `id.rsa.pub` key to remote system (min@10.10.*.*)

```
[max@localhost .ssh]$ ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub min@10.10.*.*
The authenticity of host '10.10.*.* (10.10.*.*)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 2b:bf:e1:e9:c6:76:b0:2d:a1:45:0f:2a:53:05:10:15.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.10.*.*' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
student@10.10.*.*'s password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'min@10.10.*.*'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

Now type rsync command to copy files (To automatic copy write a crontab, and write this command)

This is the syntax of `rsync`

**rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]**

```
[max@localhost .ssh]$ rsync -avz min@10.10.*.*:/home/min/test /home/max/Desktop
receiving incremental file list
test

sent 30 bytes  received 89 bytes  79.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

> **I could use rsync but there are no concise examples.**

```
$ rsync -avz /directoryname/ username@otherservername:/other/directoryname/
```

Comment: poni mentioned that **automatic backup**, so we have to do key sharing also, otherwise it will prompt password.